# how to show text along with html image link in ios

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone

i have a situation i need to display description text with images.
my sample description is like:

```
Test Article with Image and LinksTest Article with Image and Links<img alt="" src="http://stgen.eenaduindia.com/2015/Nov/2BF7AA1A-8036-4139-81FC-B9694D157F11_L_styvpf.gif" height="252" width="400" /><a href="http://eenaduindia.com">eenaduindia.com</a><a href="http://google.co.in">google.com</a>
```

i have text first and then image and then text and image. how could i show this natively without using webview.please give any suggestions or ready made sources to implement and render the above text.

Update:
can we do it asynchronously loading to textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write HTML code for this and show in UITextView.

```
    NSString *htmlString = @"<html> ... </html>";
    [textViewObject setValue:htmlString forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```

Comment: what is "step3" here.  above  [textViewObject setValue:step3 forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];

Comment: sorry it should be "htmlString". please check updated answer.

Comment: can we do this asynchronously . since my html containing more than 2 images so wont block main thread.